# Overloading in Java

Tags: java, overloading

When programming Haskell, I am used to defining the behavior of a function based on the input it receives, and not just its signature. For example:

```
f :: Int -> Int
f 2 = 4
f 3 = 9
f 4 = 16
f x = 0
```

With Java, I know I can overload a function as:

```
public String f (String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}

public String fb (Integer i) {
    System.out.println("Sorry, not a string!");
}
```

However, I was wondering if I could overload a function based on its exact input, rather than just its signature. (To avoid case/if branches)

Something like

```
public String f ("a") {
    /* do something */
}

public String f ("not a") {
    /* do something else */
}
```

Cheers,
Dario

Comment: Alas no.  The closest that you will get is an if, else if, else block within a single method.

Comment: @DarioP, you can't do that with Java

Comment: You could just try it... No, it is not possible. Additionally, your second example does not show overloading.

Comment: well, you can. Use `f( Object... args )`

Comment: This is not possible - you can use a `switch` statement.

Comment: If this is only about integer, have a look to the Java switch statement  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: @singe31 : since java 7 switch works with strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. That is not possible with Java. Best alternative is using switch cases as you already mentioned.

Comment: [The consensus](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261184/545127) is that for a ["this is not possible" answer to be acceptable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261168/is-this-is-not-possible-an-acceptable-answer), you have to *demonstrate* that it is impossible.

Comment: @VarunPhadnis The proof is that there is no such syntax in Java to declare behaviors

Answer (score 2):

Aside from defining functions like `public String f_a()` and `public String f_not_a()` and using *reflection* to call the appropriate function, Java doesn't support what you want to do.

I would **not** recommend this reflection approach as it will be a maintenance headache and the runtime overhead will be greater than branching.

Don't fight the language: use a `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

As per oracle docs

Overloaded methods are differentiated by the **number and the type of the arguments passed into** the method.

You cannot declare more than one method with the same name and the same number and type of arguments, because the compiler cannot tell them apart.

The compiler does not consider return type when differentiating methods, so you cannot declare two methods with the same signature even if they have a different return type.

Answer (score 1):

The closest and easiest thing to achieve the desired goal is using the `switch` statement in java something like this :

```
public void tryMethod(String test)
{

     switch(test)
     {
           case "a" : //do something
                 break;
           case "b" : //do some other thing
                 break;

     }
}
```

Comment: @injecteer sinca java 7 it cann process strings

Comment: did i hear that switch can accept only int in JAVA ? LOL

Comment: @SamDunk No, you didn't. Btw, it also accepts `enum`s :)

Comment: comment deleted by the commenter :D

Answer (score 1):

Overloading in java si based on class types. You should wrap your strings in two different classes

```
public interface ValueHolder {
    public String getValue();
}

public class A {
    String value;
    public A(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

public class NotA {
    String value;
    public A(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then you can overload your method as follow:

```
public String f (A s) {
    System.out.println(s.getValue());
}

public String fb (NotA s) {
    System.out.println("Overloaded");
}
```

**Or**... you can use a `switch` statement :)

In this example overloading seems a bit overengineered, but in real life problems often `switch ... case` statements tends to be a less readable and less maintainable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your example (if I understand it correctly; I don't know Haskell) is a "function" that does a one to one mapping of an integer to an integer, with a limited set of values mapping to specified values and all others mapping to 0. The closest analogy for that in Java would to use a `Map`:

```
 private static final Map<Integer,Integer> mapping = new HashMap<>();
 static {
    mapping.put(2,4);
    mapping.put(3,9);
    mapping.put(4,16);
 }

 public int f(int x) {
    Integer result = mapping.get(x);
    if (result == null) {
       return 0;
    } else {
       return result;
    }
 }
```